# How does fieldnames in matlab work

Tags: matlab

let's say I have a table calld temp returned from sql server
that looks like

```
date    column a    column b    column c
.
.
.


names               = fieldnames(temp);
names               = names(2:end);
cells               = struct2cell(temp);    
orgTS               = cell2mat(cells(2:end)');
effectiveDate       = temp.date
```

Can anyone explain what the above is doing? It's hard to test because sql server is down and I can't actually run this

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB `struct`s have fields, the names usually accessed with a `.`, and that's what `fieldnames` gets you:

> `fieldnames` Get structure field names or object properties.
>
> `NAMES = fieldnames(S)` returns a cell array of strings containing 
>       the names of the fields in structure `S`.

Your `names` variable will be a cell of strings, as stated above.  Your code gets fields `2:end`, so that looks like `{'column a','column b','column c'}`.  The line with `cell2mat(cells(2:end)');` is getting the data under these headings.

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in building a fake database until the server is up. Here is some code and its associated results.

You can evaluate the content of each variable in the command window by typing the name of the variable, in the workspace browser by double clicking on each variable , or in the editor window by pointing your mouse on each variable  (you have to set preferences, editor, display, enable datatip in edit mode)

```
%fake database
field1 = 'date';  value1 = datestr(repmat(now, 5,1));
field2 = 'cola';  value2 = rand(5,1);
field3 = 'colb';  value3 = zeros(5,1);
field4 = 'colc';  value4 = ones(5,1);

%create a temp structure
temp = struct(field1,value1,field2,value2,field3,value3,field4,value4);
```

---

The following code

```
names               = fieldnames(temp);
names               = names(2:end);
```

gives:

> names =
>
> ```
> 'cola'
> 'colb'
> 'colc'
> ```

---

```
cells               = struct2cell(temp);    
orgTS               = cell2mat(cells(2:end)');
```

gives

> orgTS =
>
> ```
> 0.7866         0    1.0000
> 0.5043         0    1.0000
> 0.4850         0    1.0000
> 0.8388         0    1.0000
> 0.0859         0    1.0000
> ```

---

```
effectiveDate       = temp.date
```

gives

```
effectiveDate =

04-Oct-2013 00:24:38
04-Oct-2013 00:24:38
04-Oct-2013 00:24:38
04-Oct-2013 00:24:38
04-Oct-2013 00:24:38
```

Comment: thanks a lot, what is the point of struct to cell and then to mat

Comment: Those are used to concatenate several fields (2:end) without naming them.